# Limit distributes over addition re: improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\int_0^\infty f(t)dt$ exists, that is $\lim_{b \to \infty} \int_0^b f(t)dt$ exists. I want to show that $\int_1^\infty f(t)dt$ exists. That is $\lim_{b \to \infty} \int_1^b f(t)dt$ makes sense.

First I thought this was easy because
\begin{align}
\lim_{b \to \infty}\int_0^b f(t)dt & = \lim_{b \to \infty}( \int_0^1 f(t)dt + \int_1^b f(t)dt ) \\
& = \int_0^1 f(t)dt +  \lim_{b \to \infty}(\int_1^b f(t)dt )
\end{align}
So $ \lim_{b \to \infty}(\int_1^b f(t)dt) = \lim_{b \to \infty}\int_0^b f(t)dt - \int_0^1 f(t)dt .$

But I had a second thought because the distributive law of limits over addition assumes that  $\int_0^1 f(t)dt$ and $\lim_{b \to \infty}(\int_1^b f(t)dt)$ converges as $b$ approaches $\infty$, which is what we are trying to prove.

Is there an easy way to show that $\int_1^\infty f(t)dt$ exists?

We assume that $f$ is a positive function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct, and your second thought isn't correct.  Look at Baby Rudin 4.34(b).  It says:  "Let $f$ and $g$ be defined on $E \subset R$.  Suppose $f(t) \to A$, $g(t) \to B$ as $t\to x$.  Then $(f+g)(t) \to A+B$."  $x$ is anything in what Rudin calls the "extended number system" which includes the reals plus $\pm\infty$.

In more detail, if $\int_a^b f$ exists then $\int_{a}^{b'} f$ exists for $a\leq b'\leq b$.  See Baby Rudin 6.12(c).  Thus if $\int_0^b f$ exists for some $b>1$, then $\int_0^1 f$ exists.  What is more, for any $b>1$, $\int_1^b f=\int_0^bf - \int_0^1 f$.  Take limits as $b\to\infty$ and you get that $\lim \int_1^b f$  exists:  note you are not exchanging limits with integrals or doing anything fancy, you are just taking limits of a sum and applying Baby Rudin 4.34(b).